# Pymysql INSERT does not insert but rising Duplicate Error

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I try to insert data via python in my mysql database, it doesn't insert the data, I find my database to be empty but if I redo the same `INSERT` command, it rises a Duplicate Error.
Here is some example for my code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                            user='user',
                            password='password',
                            db='literatur',
                            charset='utf8mb4',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "INSERT into tf_data (tf_data_id, abstract) values (4, 'TEST')"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                connection.commit
```

It is somehow connecting the database (`UPDATE` commands actually work) and increasing the auto-increment of tf_data_id.
If I however do `SELECT * FROM tf_data;` mysql gives me >> empty set (0.00 s). How to find out what the problem is?

Comment: What happening is a normal behaviour, you are trying to insert again and again the same id (i assume tf_data_id is a pk). if it is an autoincrement, change your insert into : insert into tf_data(abstract) values('test')

Comment: Should not it be `connection.commit()` instead of `connection.commit`?

Comment: The brackets already solved the problem. I could have saved some hours of becomming crazy- thanks